# drush up fails with Unknown archive format

Tags: drush

Today, I am getting an error message when I run the Drush download or update command.

```
drush up -y captcha
```

fails with

> Unable to extract /.tmp/drush_tmp_1582749966_5e56d90e14736/captcha-7.x-1.7.tar.gz. Unknown archive format. [error]

When I changed the Drush temp directory I still get the same error message. Also, same error message using php7.2, php7.3, php7.4

Why does this happen?

Comment: Even if the issue is resolved, it makes sense to tell which version of Drush you used - and Drupal version. Added: Drupal 7 I see now from the captcha version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Drush was using PHP 7.4 instead of PHP 7.3 on command line. Adding export DRUSH_PHP=/php_path to bash_profile resolved the issue. Updating and downloading Drupal modules is working again.

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.
I'm on PHP 7.4.5
The issue is fixed by upgrading drush from 8.1.15 to 8.3.3:

Change (update to 8.3.3) Drush-Version in

`~/.composer/composer.json`

and

`composer update`

Comment: Ran into the same issue this afternoon. Updating to 8.3.3 was the fix. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure you do the composer update in the correct place where your composer.json resides.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue recently, which is caused by the fact that the PHP finfo function in PHP 7.4 returns mimetype application/gzip for gzip-compressed files instead of mimetype application/x-gzip as earlier PHP versions had done. A bug report was filed, but it was decided that the change was an improvement so was not fixed (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79681).

Since my system does not have multiple PHP versions installed, I could not use either of the solutions involving the use of earlier PHP versions.

Since my system repositories do not yet include drush 8.3.3 which is reported to resolve this issue, I was not able to use that solution either.

Instead, I patched drush locally (located in /usr/share/drush on my system) with the following patch, which worked for me:

```
--- includes/drush.inc.20180206 2020-09-21 07:49:26.161595136 +0200
+++ includes/drush.inc  2020-09-21 07:49:37.012533799 +0200
@@ -891,8 +891,8 @@
   if (class_exists('finfo')) {
     $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
     $content_type = $finfo->file($filename);
+    drush_log(dt('Mime type (finfo) for !file is !ct.', array('!file' => $filename, '!ct' => $content_type)), LogLevel::DEBUG);
     if ($content_type == 'application/octet-stream') {
-      drush_log(dt('Mime type for !file is application/octet-stream.', array('!file' => $filename)), LogLevel::DEBUG);
       $content_type = FALSE;
     }
   }
@@ -972,6 +972,7 @@
 function drush_file_is_tarball($path) {
   $content_type = drush_attempt_mime_content_type($path);
   $supported = array(
+    'application/gzip',
     'application/x-bzip2',
     'application/x-gzip',
     'application/x-tar',
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but changing the default PHP version before doing the update did.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

Perform the update, then set the PHP version back.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

I ran into a permission error afterward which was fixed with the Drupal recommendations:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/site
chown -R drupal-user:www-data .
find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \;
find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;
cd /path/to/site/sites
find . -type d -name files -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
for d in ./*/files
do
   find $d -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
   find $d -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o= '{}' \;
done
find . -name .htaccess -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;
```

Everything works now.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change the php version to 7.1, then change back to 7.4 after performing the update with drush.

Answer (score 2):

The first paragraph of the answer by @Eric Negaard  well explains why it fails.

And the answer by @Hermann Schwarz should work well for a project-specific drush.

Here is how to deal with it if you are using *global* drush in you environment (and maybe Drupal 7).

If you follow the [standard installation procedure](https://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install-alternative/) of `drush`, you are probably using the tool [cgr](https://github.com/consolidation/cgr) developed by Greg Anderson (see [justification](https://pantheon.io/blog/fixing-composer-global-command)) to manage your global `drush`.

Then, `cgr update drush/drush` would do a job, which updates drush to say, 10.4.2 as of 2021-04-14, providing you are using Drupal 8 or above. However, this command would not work well with Drupal 7, because Drush Version 10 (or 9) does not support Drupal 7.

If you are using Drupal 7, do as follows - basically you must uninstall drush first and reinstall your desired version.

```bash
cgr remove drush/drush
cgr drush/drush:8.4.6
```

where `8.4.6` is the latest (or your chosen) version of drush Ver.8. See [drush-ops/drush Releases](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases) on Github to check out the latest releases.

For your information,

```bash
cgr info drush/drush | grep -i versions
```

would return the version of your cgr-installed drush (In my environment, when its version was 10, it did not match with the result of `drush --version`, which confused me).

Comment: Thank you. Updating drush with cgr worked perfect for me.

Comment: much later, this still works. I downgraded drush to exactly 8.4.6, but here using `composer global require drush/drush:8.4.6` - and it solved the issue, temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using an older version of php as stated here:

https://www.thinkbean.com/drupal-development-blog/running-drush-alternate-version-php

and then after loging in again:

`$ drush73 pm-update`